# How can I pass a flowfile attribute to a controller service?

Tags: apache-nifi

Hello Internet Hive Mind!

I need to query AWS Athena with nifi, however I need to change the staging directory (the S3 bucket & folder where the results will be saved) for each query sent.

But the s3_staging_dir property has to be set on the DBCPConnectionPool Controller Service.
How can I change the value of that property for each different flow file?
Apparently it can't be fetched by expression language alone.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure the nature of your flow where each query depends on a different staging directory, but there are a couple things to keep in mind.

1. The `DBCPConnectionPool` controller service does allow dynamic properties which evaluate expression language, but that expression language evaluation is performed when the controller service is *enabled*, so "once" per start/stop.
2. The dynamic properties on the controller service *do not* evaluate flowfile attributes.

From [Apache NiFi `DBCPConnectionPool` documentation](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-dbcp-service-nar/1.5.0/org.apache.nifi.dbcp.DBCPConnectionPool/index.html):

> Dynamic Properties:
>
> Dynamic Properties allow the user to specify both the name and value
>   of a property.
>
> ...
>
> Specifies a property name and value to be set on the JDBC
>   connection(s). If Expression Language is used, evaluation will be
>   performed upon the controller service being enabled. Note that no flow
>   file input (attributes, e.g.) is available for use in Expression
>   Language constructs for these properties. **Supports Expression
>   Language: true**

Because of your requirement that the S3 staging directory is different on every request, I think in this case, you would need to pursue one of the following options:

1. [File a Jira](https://issues.apache.org/jira/secure/CreateIssue!default.jspa) requesting native Athena support in NiFi (thoroughly explain why the existing `DBCPConnectionPool` doesn't support your use case)
2. Extend the `DBCPConnectionPool` controller service with your own `AthenaConnectionPool` controller service. There are many tutorials for building your own NiFi components, but the [NiFi Developer Guide > Developing Controller Services](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/developer-guide.html#developing-controller-service) is the best place to start. You can make a controller service which does evaluate incoming flowfile attributes when performing expression language execution, but you will need to manually trigger this, as controller services do not have an `@OnTrigger` phase of their lifecycle. If you also write a custom processor, you can invoke some "re-evaluate" method in the controller service from the `onTrigger()` method of the processor, but existing processors will not call this. Instead, you could [theoretically put a high frequency refresher in the controller service](http://www.nifi.rocks/developing-a-custom-apache-nifi-controller-service/) itself using executors, but this will definitely affect performance
3. Create multiple `DBCPConnectionPool` instances and SQL processors for each staging directory (feasible on the order of 1 - 3, otherwise abysmal)
4. Use the [`ExecuteStreamCommand`](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.5.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.ExecuteStreamCommand/index.html) processor with [`awscli`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/athena/) to execute the queries using the command-line tool. This deprives you of the NiFi native SQL tools but allows custom queries on every invocation because `ExecuteStreamCommand` can interpret the flowfile-specific attributes and use them in the query
5. Re-evaluate your flow design and see if there is a way to perform the queries without allowing for arbitrary S3 staging directories on individual query execution

Comment: Going with #4. Seems to be the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to set the property in `DBCPConnectionPool`. The query that you set in the SQL processor will output the results from Athena as flowfiles. You can connect the SQL processor to a `PutS3Object` and specify the bucket name and other necessary properties. This will write the result of your SQL query to the S3 staging directory.