# Why the ExpressionLanguageScope in DBCPConnectionPool service is limited to only 'VARIABLE_REGISTRY' and not ' FLOWFILE_ATTRIBUTES'?

Tags: apache, minify, apache-nifi, hortonworks-data-platform, hortonworks-dataflow

The `DBCPConnectionPool Service` requires 5 connection parameters to establish connection to a database as shown in the picture below  **[Marked Yellow]**
[image]

I used `UpdateAttribute Processor` to manually add these 5 connection parameters and gave them their respective values as shown in the picture below  **[Marked Yellow]**
[image]

Now, when I was trying to read the values for the connection parameters in `DBCPConnectionPool Service` through these attributes **(Shown in picture below)** , I was unable to read them.
[image]

**To know the reason why the `DBCPConnectionPool Service` was unable to read the Flowfile attributes, I went ahead to check the source code for both `DBCPConnectionPool Service` and `UpdateAttribute Processor`.**

https://github.com/apache/nifi/blob/master/nifi-nar-bundles/nifi-standard-services/nifi-dbcp-service-bundle/nifi-dbcp-service/src/main/java/org/apache/nifi/dbcp/DBCPConnectionPool.java

https://github.com/apache/nifi/blob/master/nifi-nar-bundles/nifi-update-attribute-bundle/nifi-update-attribute-processor/src/main/java/org/apache/nifi/processors/attributes/UpdateAttribute.java

Souce code for `DBCPConnectionPool Service` :
[image]

Souce code for `UpdateAttribute Processor` :
[image]

Thus, I came to know the reason why it was unable to read the values from FlowFile attributes. This is because the `ExpressionLanguageScope` is limited to `VARIABLE_REGISTRY` and not `FLOWFILE_ATTRIBUTES`.

**Now, My Question is that why the `ExpressionLanguageScope` for `DBCPConnectionPool Service` is limited to `VARIABLE_REGISTRY`. What is the reason for this limitation? The reason why I am asking this question is because I want to read the values for the connection parameters through FlowFile attributes.**

Comment: because that's an idea of the connection pool. it creates a set of connections to the destination datasource in advance, before any flowfile is coming. so it has no access to flowfile attributes during connection.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For the same question that has been asked in the [NiFi dev mailing list](http://apache-nifi-developer-list.39713.n7.nabble.com/How-can-I-pass-a-flowfile-attribute-to-a-controller-service-td18450.html), Andy had answered it in the best way possible. The reason why `DBCPConnectionPool` services or any controller services for that matter, uses `ExpressionLanguageScope.VARIABLE_REGISTRY` is that, the controller services have **no** access to the flowfiles so it won't read the flowfiles' attributes. And for the question, why it only supports `VARIABLE_REGISTRY` is:

- Just because it doesn't read flowfile attributes doesn't mean that it should not use attributes from elsewhere.
- One of the major reasons why `VARIABLE_REGISTRY` was introduced was to avoid exposing the sensitive values which is the case when we pass around such values as flowfile attributes. The controller services fit this case, because many of them use sensitive properties like `Password`.

And if you're assuming that you can make it work just changing the the scope for those properties to `ExpressionLanguageScope.FLOWFILE_ATTRIBUTES`, you're wrong. Changing them makes no sense and doesn't work, the reason is again the controller services never get to access the flowfiles.

If there is a specific requirement for you wherein you need to use different property values for different flowfiles, Andy in the original dev thread had shared some links which I'm posting again:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/49412970/70465
- https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/user-guide.html#Using_Custom_Properties

Comment: This is correct. For context about why Controller Services do not have access to flow file attributes, one reason is that they are designed to be shared by many processors. Imagine you have a large flow with 10s or 100s of processors interacting with the same DB server. It would be inefficient to have them each create their own connection or connection pool, so the idea of a controller service is that all processors that need to connect to that DB server can share a pool. If the connection properties were dynamic, driven by flow file attributes, the connection pool could not be shared.